# I want insert image and text under title in beamer

Tags: beamer

I am making a beamer presentation. I want insert image and text under title in beamer, but the image doesn't appear all. I think that date of title has empty space, so I want to move the column up.
How can I get this result?

P.s.: I used `\usebackgroundtemplate` but it seems to be only using the image, and I can't move the image just scale it with `[scale=size]`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{
    \def\\{}
} %개행 허용

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}       %그림
\graphicspath{{./image/}}   %그림 경로 설정



\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{logo.png}}
    \title{\raggedright\fontsize{40pt}{20pt}\textbf{유변학}$\left(\textbf{流變學}\right)$}
    \subtitle{\centering{\color{black}유변학: 흐름과 변형의 학문}}
    \date{}
    \maketitle
    
    \begin{columns}[t]
    \column{0.4\textwidth}
        Rheo - to flow \\
        Logos - science \\
        Ology - the study of
    \column{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{honey.png}
    \end{columns}
    
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

i work out from other site whit correcting title page setting.

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
\vbox{}
\begingroup
\centering
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%

\ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
\else%
\vskip0.25em%
{\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
\fi%

\end{beamercolorbox}%

\vskip3em\par
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
\usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
\end{beamercolorbox}

\endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: What is this? An answer? Or clarifying your question? You should provide image of frame produced by your code ...